# Failed to open configuration file '/etc/systemd/resolved.conf': Permission denied

Tags: permissions, systemd, dns, systemd-resolved

`systemctl status systemd-resolved.service` returns

```
 systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-02-01 19:47:24 CET; 15min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 65445 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 36023)
     Memory: 1.6M
        CPU: 3.572s
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─65445 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

Feb 01 19:47:20 srvides00 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd-resolved[65445]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd-resolved[65445]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd-resolved[65445]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.arpa 22.172.in-addr.>
Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd-resolved[65445]: Failed to open configuration file **'/etc/systemd/resolved.conf': Permission denied**
Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd-resolved[65445]: Failed to parse configuration file: Permission denied

Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd-resolved[65445]: **Failed to stat /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied**
Feb 01 19:47:24 srvides00 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
```

Please find below the permission details

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1406 Apr  7  2022 /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Jan 20  2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
```

What could be wrong, we are on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Getting "Temporary failure in name resolution" while ping any entries in the /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the **"Temporary failure in name resolution"** error message when trying to ping entries in the /etc/hosts, this may indicate that the systemd-resolved service is not able to resolve the hostnames to IP addresses correctly. To troubleshoot, you can try restarting the systemd-resolved service, checking the contents of the /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/systemd/resolved.conf files to ensure they are correctly configured, and checking if the entries in the /etc/hosts file are correct.

This may indicate a problem with the permissions of the files. The resolved service likely requires read access to the configuration files in order to work properly. It appears that the resolved service is being run without sufficient permissions to access the required files.

It is recommended to check the permissions on the configuration files and make sure they are set such that the resolved service can access them. For example, the owner of the file /etc/systemd/resolved.conf should be the user or group running the resolved service, or it should have the read permission for others set.